# Square shaped layout border with round inside edges

Tags: android, list, border, layer

I’m attempting to create a layout border with corners that are square on the outside and round on the inside. I’ve gathered that I need to create an .xml drawable definition composed of two shapes: one with a stroke width and corner radius and another with a stroke width only:

**The drawables**

round_border.xml

```
<shape xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
    <stroke android:width="4dp" android:color="#FF000000" />
    <padding android:left="7dp" android:top="7dp"
            android:right="7dp" android:bottom="7dp" />
    <corners android:radius="4dp" />
    <solid android:color="#FFC0C0C0" />
</shape>
```

square_border.xml

```
<shape xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
    <stroke android:width="2dp" android:color="#FF000000" />
    <solid android:color="#FFC0C0C0" />
</shape>
```

Each of these works independantly as a border when appliedby itself like so:

```
android:background="@drawable/round_border"
```

but when they either or both are added to an item-list drawable like so:

composite_border.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<shape xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
    <layer-list>
        <item android:drawable="@drawable/round_border"/>
        <!-- <item android:drawable="@drawable/square_border"/> -->
    </layer-list>
</shape>
```

and:

```
android:background="@drawable/composite_border"
```

The layout's background is completely black instead of just a black border.

Does anyone know how to make the layer list work for this task?

Answer (score 5):

From [Shape Drawable Doc](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/resources/drawable-resource.html#Shape) you can see that shape can't have layer-list inside so you should define your composite_border.xml like this

```
<layer-list xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android" >
    <item android:drawable="@drawable/square_border"/>
    <item android:drawable="@drawable/round_border"/>
</layer-list>
```

note that I changed the order of your items inside the layer-list as stated in the documentation of layer-list
`Each drawable in the list is drawn in the order of the list—the last drawable in the list is drawn on top` 
and you want it to be squared from outside

Answer (score 4):

**Try this will work fine enough:**

`solid` is **background color**

`stroke` is **border**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<shape
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:shape="rectangle">
   <solid 
       android:color="@color/white"/>
   <stroke android:width="1dp" android:color="#ffaaaaaa" />
   <size 
       android:width="15dp"
        android:height="15dp"/>
</shape>
```

Comment: what about if I want a padding bw border and solid ?

Answer (score 4):

**Create a xml file like round_background.xml:**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<shape
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:shape="oval">
   <solid 
       android:color="#CCCC33"/>
   <size 
       android:width="35dp"
        android:height="35dp"/>
</shape>
```

**In the layout set as background**

```
<LinearLayout
    android:id="@+id/layout_wellbeing"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:layout_weight="1"
    android:gravity="center"
    android:background="@drawable/rounded_corner_leuvan"
    android:orientation="horizontal" >
</LinearLayout>
```

Answer (score 2):

square_border.xml

```
<shape xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
    <stroke android:width="2dp" 
            android:color="#FF000000"
    />
    <solid android:color="#FFC0C0C0" />
</shape>
```

composite_border.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<shape xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
    <layer-list>
        <item android:drawable="@drawable/round_border"/>
        <!-- <item android:drawable="@drawable/square_border"/> -->
    </layer-list>
</shape>
```

watch out the comments and the quotation marks! =]

Comment: Thanks - still looking for the answer though.