# Round Border LinerLayout

Tags: android, android-layout, android-linearlayout, android-xml

so the question [How to add border around linear layout except at the bottom?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10457135/how-to-add-border-around-linear-layout-except-at-the-bottom) answers my question partially but i cant seem to figure out how to make the corners round ..

Comment: Did you try this : http://stackoverflow.com/q/6514114/693752 ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. Create a XML file named `round_border` in your layout folder.
2. **Now put this code in your XML file :**

   ```
   <shape xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"> 
   <stroke android:width="4dp" android:color="#FF00FF00" /> 
   <solid android:color="#ffffff" /> 
   <padding android:left="7dp" android:top="7dp" 
           android:right="7dp" android:bottom="7dp" /> 
   <corners android:radius="10dp" />
   ```
3. Now use this file as a background of your `LinearLayout` like this :

   > ```
   > <LinearLayout android:id="@+id/LinearLayout01"
   > android:layout_width="fill_parent"
   > android:layout_height="fill_parent"
   > android:orientation="vertical"
   > android:padding="20dip"
   > android:background="@drawable/round_border">
   > ```

Comment: just one problem my app has a background image anyway to just allow the border to be seen?

Comment: @JacobAnthonyTonna are you looking for image with rounded corners?

Comment: @JacobAnthonyTonna i don't think you can both set for linear layout. I guess you are looking for image with rounded corners

Comment: For transparent background you can use "<solid android:color="#00ffffff" />"

Comment: wait theres one huge problem i cant have 2 items in there without one moving or overlapping the other...

Answer (score 1):

In your linear layout

```
   android:background="@drawable/bkg"
```

Define the below xml in drawable folder.

bkg.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?> 
<shape xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:shape="rectangle"> 
<solid android:color="#10EB0A"/>    
<stroke android:width="3dp"
    android:color="#0FECFF" /> 
<padding android:left="5dp"
     android:top="5dp"
     android:right="5dp"
     android:bottom="5dp"/> 
<corners android:bottomRightRadius="7dp"
     android:bottomLeftRadius="7dp" 
     android:topLeftRadius="7dp"
     android:topRightRadius="7dp"/> 
</shape>
```

Answer (score 0):

this is a custom Drawable you can use:

```
class RoundedImageDrawable extends Drawable {

    private Bitmap mBitmap;
    private Matrix mMatrix;
    private Path mPath;
    private float mRx;
    private float mRy;

    public RoundedImageDrawable(Resources res , int id, float rx, float ry) {
        mBitmap = BitmapFactory.decodeResource(res, id);
        mMatrix = new Matrix();
        mPath = new Path();
        mRx = rx;
        mRy = ry;
    }

    @Override
    protected void onBoundsChange(Rect bounds) {
        RectF src = new RectF(0, 0, mBitmap.getWidth(), mBitmap.getHeight());
        RectF dst = new RectF(bounds);
        mMatrix.setRectToRect(src, dst, Matrix.ScaleToFit.FILL);
        mPath.addRoundRect(dst, mRx, mRy, Direction.CW);
    }

    @Override
    public void draw(Canvas canvas) {
        canvas.save();
        canvas.clipPath(mPath);
        canvas.drawBitmap(mBitmap, mMatrix, null);
        canvas.restore();
    }

    @Override
    public void setAlpha(int alpha) {
    }

    @Override
    public void setColorFilter(ColorFilter cf) {
    }

    @Override
    public int getOpacity() {
        return PixelFormat.TRANSLUCENT;
    }
}
```

and use it in your Activity:

```
LinearLayout ll = findViewById(R.id.layout);
Drawable d = new RoundedImageDrawable(getResources(), R.drawable.background, 20, 20);
ll.setBackgroundDrawable(d);
```